# How to add X509 certificate TLS encryption in tigervnc in linux?

Tags: linux, vnc, tigervnc

In tigervnc, how to add and deploy X509 certificate TLS encryption in linux environment?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan That seems pretty comprehensive... why not put it in as an answer?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I also generated private key in PEM format, and create a signing certificate in PEM format? Edit the configuration files, and copy the certificate to the client. But got the error of "Authentiction failure:error loading x509 certificate or key". And how to set GnuTLSPriority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `x0vncserver` man page

```
-SecurityTypes sec-types
    Specify which security scheme to use for incoming connections. Valid values are a comma separated list of None, VncAuth, Plain, TLSNone, TLSVnc, TLSPlain, X509None, X509Vnc and X509Plain. Default is VncAuth,TLSVnc.

−X509Cert path

Path to a X509 certificate in PEM format to be used for all X509 based security types (X509None, X509Vnc, etc.).

−X509Key path

Private key counter part to the certificate given in X509Cert. Must also be in PEM format.

−GnuTLSPriority priority

GnuTLS priority string that controls the TLS sessionâs handshake algorithms. See the GnuTLS manual for possible values. Default is NORMAL.
```

So basically you have to set `-SecurityTypes X509...` and then provide path of your cert and private key in `-X509Cert` and `-X509Key`. The `-GnuTLSPriority` set the GnuTLS priority.

The possible GnuTLS priority is exhaustive as there are lot of cipher suits. Read from [GnuTLS docs](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Priority-Strings.html#Priority-Strings)

Apology :I am not sure if this is the right answer because it is untested, and I never used X509 certs for VNC, (well, my web browsers read them for me). It looks too clumsy in comment.

Comment: I still got the error of "Authentiction failure:error loading x509 certificate or key", following is my custom user configuration file, pls help to check
session=gnome
geometry=2000x1200
alwaysshared
securitytypes=X509Vnc,VncAuth
X509Key=/root/.vnc/ssl/ca.private.rsa.4096.key.pem
X509Cert=/root/.vnc/ssl/ca.sign.rsa.4096.key.pem
GnuTLSPriority=NORMAL

Comment: Is the user root user, otherwise how could the user read from `/root`?

Comment: It's an overlook. It works now. I use ordinary user to do all the steps and worked, the problem is when I switched users, privilege issues happens. Thank you very much for your help.